# C++ - Putting auto_ptrs in a shared_ptr vector

Tags: c++, memory-management, smart-pointers

I have a vector of shared_ptrs. I'm currently putting auto_ptrs into it. Is that okay or will things break?

Room.hpp:

```
vector<shared_ptr<Item>> items;
void addItem(auto_ptr<Item>);
```

main:

```
room.addItem(auto_ptr<Item>(new Item(...)));
```

Comment: Why not make `addItem` a forwarding template and do away with the intermediate pointer altogether?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't. `auto_ptr` has been deprecated in C++11 and criticized since its inception because of its strange ownership semantics. Copying an `auto_ptr` will transfer ownership to the copied object. In your case that might be alright, but if you do, for example:

```
auto_ptr<Item> x = room[1]; // ouch
```

things start to get ugly.

Use a `std::shared_ptr` if you require shared ownership or a `std::unique_ptr` if you don't. If you don't have a C++11 compiler, use Boost.SmartPointers. There is also a [Boost.Pointer Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) if you only use pointers for polymorphism instead of shared ownership.

If you really want to keep your API that way, you need to use:

```
addItem(auto_ptr<Item>&&);
```

Keep in mind that the `auto_ptr` will be empty afterwards.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. Then in my question is it okay to add a unique_ptr to the vector of shared_ptrs?

Comment: "despised" is a strong word! :) I like it for it's relative simplicity in conveying ownership. The fact that it can't go into a container is a weak point, but if you don't need that functionality, it served a purpose... :)

Comment: @JeanFinley `unique_ptrS` cannot be copied. Only moved, you need to emplace construct them or use `room.push_back(std::move(ptr))` to put them into containers.

Comment: @Nim I made that sound fairer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use `auto_ptr` in any STL containers. And don't use `auto_ptr` at all! There is good article about `auto_ptr`'s troubles on **gotw**: [GotW#25](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/025.htm).
2. Use `boost::ptr_vector`.

Answer (score 1):

That will work - `shared_ptr` has a constructor that transfers ownership from an `auto_ptr`.

However, `auto_ptr` is best avoided due to its strange destructive-copy semantics; in C++11, `unique_ptr` should be preferred for single transferable ownership. That can also be used to initialise a `shared_ptr`.